# F# Checked Arithmetics Scope

Tags: f#, module, scope, operators, math

F# allows to use checked arithmetics by opening `Checked` module, which redefines standard operators to be checked operators, for example:

```
open Checked
let x = 1 + System.Int32.MaxValue // overflow
```

will result arithmetic overflow exception.

But what if I want to use checked arithmetics in some small scope, like C# allows with keyword `checked`:

```
int x = 1 + int.MaxValue;             // ok
int y = checked { 1 + int.MaxValue }; // overflow
```

How can I control the scope of operators redefinition by opening `Checked` module or make it smaller as possible?

Comment: Conversely, is it possible to invoke "checked" on all statements in a C# project?

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt - The converse can be accomplished with compiler options, either in the IDE or the command line.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can always define a separate operator, or use shadowing, or use parens to create an inner scope for temporary shadowing:

```
let f() =
    // define a separate operator
    let (+.) x y = Checked.(+) x y
    try 
        let x = 1 +. System.Int32.MaxValue
        printfn "ran ok"
    with e ->
        printfn "exception"
    try 
        let x = 1 + System.Int32.MaxValue
        printfn "ran ok"
    with e ->
        printfn "exception"
    // shadow (+)
    let (+) x y = Checked.(+) x y
    try 
        let x = 1 + System.Int32.MaxValue
        printfn "ran ok"
    with e ->
        printfn "exception"
    // shadow it back again
    let (+) x y = Operators.(+) x y
    try 
        let x = 1 + System.Int32.MaxValue
        printfn "ran ok"
    with e ->
        printfn "exception"
    // use parens to create a scope
    (
        // shadow inside
        let (+) x y = Checked.(+) x y
        try 
            let x = 1 + System.Int32.MaxValue
            printfn "ran ok"
        with e ->
            printfn "exception"
    )            
    // shadowing scope expires
    try 
        let x = 1 + System.Int32.MaxValue
        printfn "ran ok"
    with e ->
        printfn "exception"


f()    
// output:
// exception
// ran ok
// exception
// ran ok
// exception
// ran ok
```

Finally, see also the `--checked+` compiler option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 19):

Here is a complicated (but maybe interesting) alternative. If you're writing something serious then you should probably use one of the Brians suggestions, but just out of curiosity, I was wondering if it was possible to write F# computation expression to do this. You can declare a type that represents `int` which should be used only with checked operations:

```
type CheckedInt = Ch of int with
  static member (+) (Ch a, Ch b) = Checked.(+) a b
  static member (*) (Ch a, Ch b) = Checked.(*) a b
  static member (+) (Ch a, b) = Checked.(+) a b
  static member (*) (Ch a, b) = Checked.(*) a b
```

Then you can define a computation expression builder (this isn't really a monad at all, because the types of operations are completely non-standard):

```
type CheckedBuilder() = 
  member x.Bind(v, f) = f (Ch v)      
  member x.Return(Ch v) = v
let checked = new CheckedBuilder()
```

When you call 'bind' it will automatically wrap the given integer value into an integer that should be used with `checked` operations, so the rest of the code will use checked `+` and `*` operators declared as members. You end up with something like this:

```
checked { let! a = 10000 
          let! b = a * 10000 
          let! c = b * 21 
          let! d = c + 47483648 // !
          return d }
```

This throws an exception because it overflows on the marked line. If you change the number, it will return an `int` value (because the `Return` member unwraps the numeric value from the `Checked` type). This is a bit crazy technique :-) but I thought it may be interesting!

(Note `checked` is a keyword reserved for future use, so you may prefer choosing another name)

Comment: It's not that great though. You can write `checked { return Int32.MaxValue + 1 }` and it will be actually unchecked, because to make a number _checked_, you need to pass it to `let!` first...